# Create table with CTEs in SQL

Tags: sql-server, common-table-expression, create-table

I have one CTE I am trying to create a table from and not sure what I am doing wrong? I keep getting an error "Incorrect syntax near ';'."

```
create table ATB AS

;WITH 


rpt_dts as (

select 
        CONVERT(varchar(12),GETDATE() -30, 101) productivity_srt_date 
       ,CONVERT(varchar(12),GETDATE(), 101) productivity_end_date
       ,CONVERT(varchar(12),'1/1/2017', 101) DenialStrt_date  
       ,CONVERT(varchar(12),GETDATE(), 101) ME_end_date   


) select * from rpt_dts
```

Comment: This question is a great example of why I hate people using the syntax `;WITH`, as it incorrectly teaches people its a `;WITH` expression, not a `WITH` expression that may follow a **correctly** terminated statement. `;` goes at the end of all your statements, not at the start of a `WITH` or `MERGE`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Server does not support CTAs:

```
;WITH rpt_dts as (
  select 
        CONVERT(varchar(12),GETDATE() -30, 101) productivity_srt_date 
       ,CONVERT(varchar(12),GETDATE(), 101) productivity_end_date
       ,CONVERT(varchar(12),'1/1/2017', 101) DenialStrt_date  
       ,CONVERT(varchar(12),GETDATE(), 101) ME_end_date   
) 
select * 
into ATB        -- into clause is a workaround
from rpt_dts
```

Comment: Apparently only [Azure SQL Data Warehouse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-data-warehouse/sql-data-warehouse-develop-ctas) supports it.

Comment: Thank you so much! Did not know that . I come from Oracle enviroment so still trying to get use to SSMS.

Answer (score 1):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/1e6b6/1)

**MS SQL Server 2017 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE #ATB (
productivity_srt_date VARCHAR(250)
,productivity_end_date VARCHAR(250)
, DenialStrt_date VARCHAR(250)
, ME_end_date VARCHAR(250)
);
```

**Query 1**:

```
WITH rpt_dts as (

select 
        CONVERT(varchar(12),GETDATE() -30, 101) productivity_srt_date 
       ,CONVERT(varchar(12),GETDATE(), 101) productivity_end_date
       ,CONVERT(varchar(12),'1/1/2017', 101) DenialStrt_date  
       ,CONVERT(varchar(12),GETDATE(), 101) ME_end_date   
)

select * 
into #ATB       
from rpt_dts
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/1e6b6/1/0)**:

Comment: I think you will need the semicolon at the end of the `CREATE TABLE` command.